# Brain regeneration - book recommendation

Tags: brain, book-recommendation

Searching for an up-to-date book on regenerative brain medicine with a focus on stem cell therapy. 
Also interesting in genetic engineering of neuronal stem cells for this purpose.

Alternatively, a comprehensive review article is welcomed too.

Comment: I modified the wording - feel free to roll back.

Comment: Are you interested in neural regeneration in strictly the CNS, or in the PNS as well?

Answer (score 1):

Neural regeneration is addressed broadly in this chapter from a book published in 2013 (though I would say for a topic such as this, you're probably going to want to read primary literature or recent, less comprehensive reviews in addition to any book chapters published in the few years):

[Neural Regeneration](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F82_2012_302) by Melissa M. Steward, Akshayalakshmi Sridhar, Jason S. Meyer, published in New Perspectives in Regeneration.

The chapter includes two sections on stem cell therapy and one section on reprogramming of somatic cells to neural lineages.

Answer (score -1):

Regeneration... What a lovely word since 2010
You could start with [This](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/13/5845.full) text published on 2010 which shows how P21 and it's controller(P53 gene) could regulate regeneration of mammalians' body parts and within them is neurons too.

[image: Regeneration of a hole on ear of MRL mouse or p21 knockout one]

Regeneration of a hole on ear of MRL mouse or p21 knockout one
This event was accidentally observed ten years before the text get published.
They just couldn't find the ear tagged mice, because there was no hole on their ear anymore.

And you could continue with [this](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/16/19/5961.full) text which explains:
p53-Independent Cyclin G Expression in a Group of Mature Neurons and Its Enhanced Expression during Nerve Regeneration

Google Scholar is full of texts, experiments and their results which you need to gadder your information about pathways just by studying and comparing them.
But the most interesting one of them for me was p21 knocked out mice.

As physics helps computation world(Quantum Computers) to do biophysical calculations faster and faster, watching how these proteins and genes play with each other in a 3D simulated human cell like software, will not be a dream anymore.

hope it helps

Comment: You've included figures from PNAS, which could get Biology SE in trouble over copyright issues, especially since I do not believe the article in question is Open Access.

Comment: PNAS's image is removed and users could have access to it and their related full text through links provided for them while they are open for public if you search on google scholar.